# PHP simplexml results in Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in error from curl

Tags: php, curl, simplexml

I must be doing something obviously wrong here:

I'm using Curl to retrieve data from beyond a logon saved as $result. The XML looks like:

```
<data>
  <option>...</option>
  <option>...</option>
  <option>...</option>
  <items>
    <item title="label">
      <detail_1="abc">
      <detail_2="def">
    </item>
    <item title="label2">
      <detail_1="def">
      <detail_2="ghi">
    </item>
   </items>
</data>
```

I need all the data from each 'item' group only.

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

foreach($xml->data->items->item as $item)  
  {

  echo $item["label"].'<br>';
  }
```

The result is

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ....
```

I have not used this function before. Please advise.

Comment: I think you are trying to go one element too deep for loop elements. Try $xml->data->items as $item.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work either. I get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `echo $item["label"].'<br>';` try this one

```
echo $item['title'].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You do like this since the one you want to print is an attribute of the item tag

```
foreach($xml->data->items->item->attributes() as $key=>$val)  
  {

  echo $val.'<br>';
  }
```